# VBA, select and delete variating table segments via selection in user form

Tags: excel, segments, vba

[image]

I have a table with projects in column c, each project has topics in column d each topic has dates in column e. The number of content in c d and e is variable. (I have buttons to add new projects, new topics to each project and new dates to each topic).  Accordingly I need to be able to delete projects topics and dates. As it is displayed in the picture I have a user form to choose the exact path of what should be deleted. For deleting topics this works except for the last topic. The last topic gives me an error. For deleting dates I don't even get to displaying the dates in the listbox. Any suggestions for a better solution?

Comment: Did you really took a photo of your screen and posted it to StackOverflow?

Comment: Since you use UserForm, there might be some code. Please, remake your question with the code and read this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm very sorry about the photo and the missing code but I could only send it by phone and i'm not allowed to send anything from my workplace. I thought maybe someone has a general suggestion on how to approach the problem. Thanks in advance